# Shortcodes do not work in own template

Tags: theme-development, themes, shortcode

I have a big problem rendering shortcodes in my template I designed for my Tennis Club which works fine. However, now I wanted to integrate the standard WordPress Gallery, which is implemented by a shortcode but the shortcode is not being displayed as a normal Gallery, it is displayed as a text without any images. Is there a way I can fix this?

Code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $options = get_option('tcs_theme_options'); ?>
<section id="page-content">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="headerpic">
            <?php 
            $url = get_the_permalink();
            $title = get_the_title();
            $content = get_the_content();
            $categories = get_the_category(', ');
            $date = get_the_date('d.m.Y');

            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                the_post_thumbnail();
            } else {
                slideshow();
            }?>
        </div>
        <section class="content">
            <h1><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a><span style="font-size: 14px;"></span></h1>
            <p><?php echo $content; ?></p>
            <div class="options col-xs-12">
                    <span class="fa fa-calendar pull-right"> <?php echo $date; ?></span>
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>  
</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please post your code, and explain what you have tried to fix your issue.

Comment: Which function used in the theme to display the content? Try `do_shortcode( get_the_content() );` or `apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );` in your post file.

Comment: Hi, I used the get_the_content(). In the following is my code.

Comment: @Karthikeyani thank you for your solution, now I have been able to solve it with the apply_filters.

Comment: @M. Dreisbusch Glad to hear :) I will post my answer separately. Pls accept the answer and upvote.

Answer (score 1):

`get_the_content` doesn't apply all of the filters that `the_content` runs before outputting the result. You can fix this by simply using:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

in place of:

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

If you look at [the source for `the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/#source-code), you'll see the extra step it performs on what is returned from `get_the_content`.

Comment: @M.Dreisbusch if your code is now working and this answer has answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the shortcode to your template like this:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[*shortcode here*]'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try `do_shortcode( get_the_content() );` or `apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );` in your post file.